# How can I have both years and string-formatted x-axes in two charts in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having a problem adding two charts in HighCharts: one has just decades, and the other has the same decades but also with categories like "year one", etc.  The two charts don't seem to be able to be put onto the same chart.

I'm getting HighCharts Error #19: Too Many Ticks.

Here are my categories:

```
categories: ["RNV-A", "RNV-B", "RNV-C", "RNV-D", 
"RNV-E", "RNV-F", "RNV-G", "RNV-H", 
"RNV-I", "P.I.", "1910", "1920", 
"1930", "1940", "1950", "1960", 
"1970", "1980", "1990", "2000", 
"2010", "2020", "2030", "2040", 
"2050", "2060"],
```

And the values which include all categories:

```
[40.510191198250766, 40.510191198250766, 40.510191198250766, 40.510191198250766, 40.510191198250766, 40.510191198250766, 40.510191198250766, 40.510191198250766, 40.510191198250766, 40.510191198250766, 42.44299597201156, 41.351219164431505, 39.776804170262345, 38.248217460058335, 36.702829971428535, 35.069195968318716, 33.79982485286693, 33.098321602721086, 32.828589353935875, 32.47115630145776, 32.06982734169106, 31.421843607968913, 30.92053153916419, 30.528508779591846, 30.199389512342062, 29.806527065694834]
```

And with only the decades:

```
[{"y": 54592.30356899987, "x": "1910"}, {"y": 53188.00565025002, "x": "1920"}, {"y": 51162.91436399994, "x": "1930"}, {"y": 49196.769708000036, "x": "1940"}, {"y": 47209.01505074996, "x": "1950"}, {"y": 45107.75331424995, "x": "1960"}, {"y": 43475.02471700008, "x": "1970"}, {"y": 42572.71616149999, "x": "1980"}, {"y": 42225.77305650002, "x": "1990"}, {"y": 41766.024792750046, "x": "2000"}, {"y": 41249.815418250124, "x": "2010"}, {"y": 40416.34634075002, "x": "2020"}, {"y": 39771.53369224994, "x": "2030"}, {"y": 39267.29441775001, "x": "2040"}, {"y": 38843.964760249975, "x": "2050"}, {"y": 38338.64543824998, "x": "2060"}]
```

Here's a jsfiddle that has two buttons: first one adds all the categories dataset, and the second one adds the dataset that only covers the decades:

http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/R82T3/

I've tried adding tickPixelInterval like the error page suggests: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/19

I've tried adding min, minTickInterval, maxTickInterval, tickInterval, as well.  I've also tried adjusting the `plotOptions.series.pointInterval`:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval

I can't seem able to get these charts together.  **I think** because it converts the decades to datetimes, but it doesn't convert the dataset with the strings as x-axis values.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

### The problem

I can't get both datasets onto the same chart.  It doesn't seem able to have datasets with one as decades and the other as a mixture of decades and strings.  How can I solve this?

Comment: You have so many different things going on in that code that make it hard to see where the problem might be.  If you can come up with a simplified example with static data, it will be much easier to pinpoint both what you're after and why it's not doing what you want.

Comment: Jsfiddle has been updated @jlbriggs.  Sorry for making it complicated.  I thought maybe there was a simpler solution: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/R82T3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data does not correspond to the category by its name, but by its array index.

So, with your categories array,  the x value for "RNV-A" would be 0. "RNV-B" would be 1, "RNV-C" would be 2, and so on.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you think this is part of the problem though?  The dataset that includes the "RNV" decades don't have an explicit x-value.  I just passed an array, which automatically gets filled into the categories.

Comment: I was simply responding to what's in your code that you posted, where you are specifying the category name as the x value...

Comment: Your post title, your questions, and your code examples all seem to be discussing different things :) perhaps if you clarify the actual question...

Comment: The question is how can I get both charts (datasets) on the same chart.  I'll update.

Comment: You're right.  The problem was that I had the x values as strings of the decade.  I wasn't using indices for the "RNV" categories, but `"1910"` should have instead been `10`.  Sorry that I misunderstood you.  I'm awarding you with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1) categories - You can use label formatter and check if it is number, http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter

2) X value cannot be a string, it needs to be number. In case when you would like to have datetime type of chart, you can use [pointStart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart) / [pointInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval), and then set tickInterval on xAxis (time in miliseconds)